# How to split rows of a pyspark dataframe based on a list of row numbers?

Tags: list, sorting, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I've created a pyspark dataframe that figuratively looks like this:-

```python
>>> df

f1 | f2 | ... | fn | row_num
------------------------------
10 | 50 | ... |100 |    1
20 | 50 | ... |200 |    2
30 | 50 | ... |300 |    3
40 | 50 | ... |400 |    4
50 | 50 | ... |500 |    5
```

I also then created randomized list of row numbers as follows:-

```python
my_list = [[2, 5],[4, 1, 3]]
```

Depending on the structure of this list, I wish to create pyspark dataframes as follows:-

```python
>>> split_df[0]

    f1 | f2 | ... | fn | row_num
    ------------------------------
    20 | 50 | ... |200 |    2
    50 | 50 | ... |500 |    5

>>> split_df[1]

    f1 | f2 | ... | fn | row_num
    ------------------------------
    40 | 50 | ... |400 |    4
    10 | 50 | ... |100 |    1
    30 | 50 | ... |300 |    3
```

How do I split my `df` according to `my_list` of row numbers?

I do not wish to use `df.RandomSplit()` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you want to split your DataFrame into a list, based on the values of `my_list`.

You can use `pyspark.sql.Column.isin` in a list comprehension:

```python
from pyspark.sql.functions import col
split_df = [df.where(col('row_num').isin(x)) for x in my_list]
```